# Seting Excel PowerView properties from C# VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

Is there any possibility to get access to the Excel's 2013 PowerView Dashboard properties, especially Font and FontSize properties from C# program (using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel lib)?
Kind regards!